# 2 dimensional cellular automaton for prime twins?

Tags: prime-numbers, cellular-automata, twin-primes

Is there a 'simple' 2 dimensional cellular automaton to generate all prime twins ?

With 'simple' I mean not too many states per cell and not so many rules.
Thus a universal turing machine equivalent cellular automaton is not 'simple'.

Comment: Is there one that generates all primes?  That would seem to be a less specialized place to start.

Comment: @mjqxxxx : Well there are such because of the universality of cell auto. But if there exist such simple ones is another matter. I believe the answer to that is also yes. I believe I have seen such but Im not sure. Was there an example of that in NKS ? Maybe I saw it there.

Comment: Right, I meant a simple, potentially non-universal one, like you're asking about here.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there is one for prime numbers in  wolfram's site:
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PrimeGeneratingCellularAutomaton/

Source Code is also available on the right side of the page.

Comment: Thanks , but I have no permission to the source code.
Could you give it here ? Also Im not so good with code, maybe you can explain the rule ? Like in rule 30 or such.

Comment: @mick You can go [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/sourcecode.html?demoname=PrimeGeneratingCellularAutomaton&demodisplayname=Prime-Generating%20Cellular%20Automaton) for the sourcecode.

Comment: Thanks Mahmud +1
But I do not understand the math behind it. ( Im not so good with code either )

Comment: I think that this is the author: https://www.facebook.com/joebolte
you might want to contact him, perhaps he could father explain the logic.

Comment: It seems this is the classical construction by [P. C. Fischer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_C._Fischer) : P.C. Fisher

"Generation on primes by one dimentional real time iterative array"

J. ACM, 12 (1965), pp. 388–394

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pay Wolfram if you want to study and understand his code, he is not an 'open source' sort of guy! I have questions about the rules he supplies in his book 'A New Kind of Science': I am developing a browser based automaton and his prime automaton rules do not produce the same result for me. Very probably my understanding of how to interpret his given rules is incorrect but I have emailed him about this but he has not replied yet!